# if i select combobox values then automatically other combobox values shoulde be view based on first combobox in c# silverlight

Tags: c#, combobox, silverlight-4.0

```
namespace combobox
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.Items.Add("TAMIL NADU");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("KERALA");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("MAHARASTRA");
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            comboBox3.Items.Clear();
            comboBox4.Items.Clear();
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "TAMIL NADU")
            {

                comboBox2.Items.Add("chennai");
                comboBox3.Items.Add("madurai");
                comboBox4.Items.Add("trichy");
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "KERALA")
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add("kozhicode");
                comboBox3.Items.Add("trivandrum");
                comboBox4.Items.Add("ernakulam");
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "MAHARASTRA")
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add("pune");
                comboBox3.Items.Add("mumbai");
                comboBox4.Items.Add("nabi mumbai");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

this is my xaml.cs file , this one is worked but not automatically the values are displayed in combo box based on first combo box

Comment: Does the `comboBox1_SelectionChanged` get hit? When it does, what is the value of `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`?

Comment: yes it hit, the value is tamilnadu,kerala,maharastra

Comment: Lowercase? `==` is case-sensitive. Other than that I don't see anything wrong...